# Receiving "No active connections found for master" while trying to connect Aurora read instance from java

Tags: java, mariadb, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have already created a bug report(https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJ-793) on MariaDB Jira but want to make sure it is a bug and there is nothing to do my side. I contacted the AWS support but they weren't very helpful.

We had problems with our lambda while connecting to the read database through read cluster URL. 
I was able to isolate the problem in my local tunneling through the nat instance. I have no problems running the same code against the write instance. This is the Java test code I used.

```
    private static final String connectionString
            = "jdbc:mariadb:aurora://***.cluster-***.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/db";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("user", user);
        properties.setProperty("password", password);
        DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(10);
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, properties)) {
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from exchange limit 1")) {
                resultSet.next();
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
            }

        } catch (SQLException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And I am receiving this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Communications link failure with primary. No active connection found for master. 
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.AbstractMastersListener.throwFailoverMessage(AbstractMastersListener.java:563)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.impl.MastersSlavesListener.checkInitialConnection(MastersSlavesListener.java:350)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.impl.MastersSlavesListener.initializeConnection(MastersSlavesListener.java:179)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.FailoverProxy.<init>(FailoverProxy.java:120)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:607)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:150)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:89)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at com.company.ConnectionTestJava.main(ConnectionTestJava.java:19)
```

Have anyone faced this issue? It is hard to believe that I would be the only one facing this. Is it related to my setup or it is a bug? If it is a bug is there a workaround while waiting for a solution?

Comment: is aws port open, so that you can connect? 
AFAIK you need to edit inbound rules to be able to connect from outside

Comment: I use ssh tunneling through the nat instance. The instances does not have direct external access. You can check sshuttle  to do that.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same exception. Here is what worked for me.
So the issue here is with the protocol string, it needs to be changed from jdbc:mariadb:aurora to jdbc:mariadb and it works just fine.
I got this idea by looking at the mysql driver connection protocol and gave it a try and it worked!

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I avoided it because with the aurora string there comes the  benefit of auto failover. It is more important us than to be able to use the read database.